# ssh.net maintain conversation with server

Tags: ssh.net

I am looking to persist a conversation with a remote server using ssh.net

What i am doing is connecting to a host, sending a command like change directory... to some directory besides root. Store the results value off as a global.

Then i am sending another command via RunCommand() to check the current directory...

What is happening is, i am getting the root directory, not the directory i just changed to in the initial run command.

What it seems is happening is, while the connection to the server has remained open i have somehow reset the terminal session thereby losing the conversation i was having with the server.

Does anyone know how to persist a conversation with a remote server using ssh.net so i can send multiple commands and have the state persist?

E.g. command 1 = cd/somedir
command 2 = pwd and the result of command 2 to is /somedir

Comment: What code have you tried? Editing your question to show your code will help people help you. Also adding another tag to accompany the code will increase visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g. command 1 = cd/somedir command 2 = pwd and the result of command 2 to is /somedir

Your example seems just fine. But I think, you are expecting to change directory and run the second command in that directory.

Server connection is an ssh tunnel to the server, it doesn't start a shell. RunCommand() creates a shell and runs a command, the second RunCommand also creates a new shell and runs the command, so change directory does not persist between commands.

After establishing connection, use a ShellStream to create a shell from which you can send and receive interactive commands from.

A sample from [codeplex](https://sshnet.codeplex.com/discussions?searchText=shellstream):

```
    string command = "your command";

    using (var ssh = new SshClient(connectionInfo))
{
    ssh.Connect();
    string reply = String.Empty;

    try
    {
    using (var shellStream = ssh.CreateShellStream("dumb", 0, 0, 0, 0, BUFFERSIZE))
        {
            // Wait for promt for 10 seconds, if time expires, exception is thrown
            reply = shellStream.Expect(new Regex(@":.*>"), new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));
            shellStream.WriteLine(command);

            // Wait for Read for 10 seconds, if time expires, exception is thrown
            string result = shellStream.ReadLine(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  This is exactly the issue, i needed to use the shellstream class to maintain a conversation.